# Yii 2 used with AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, yii, yii2, yii-extensions

any experience with using AngularJS with the Yii Framework (best would be version 2)? I am searching for some plugin or similar which would help me easily integrate AngularJS into Yii to work nicely together.
Is it easily possible, or is it too much overhead to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, google haven't mentioned any noticable plugin or library for that, and imo it's kind of overkill. But if you still want to have a try (dear lord have mercy) - you should make it two differnet applications connected only by REST Api implemented with Yii.